# How to pipe info from wmic to a txt doc

Tags: cmd, wmic

I need to take the info i get from running wmic:root\cli>/node:COMPUTERNAME product get name,version,vendor to a txt document I've been searching for the answer but can't seem to find it. I've done it before but you know how it goes if you don't do something all the time you forget.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WMIC` has a Global `/OUTPUT` switch, which must preceed any `<command>`. To direct `/OUTPUT` to a file,

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\WMIC.exe /OUTPUT:<path><filename> product get name,version,vendor
```

Allegedly, the destination of `/OUTPUT:` can be configured to `CLIPBOARD`, `STDOUT` or `<filename>`, but I've yet to get it to operate as desired.

I envision querying a host to check for the presence of an installed app. Something along the lines of,

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\WMIC.exe /OUTPUT:STDOUT | Find "<app-name-here>" product get name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
wmic /node:COMPUTERNAME product get name,version,vendor >output.txt
```

use `>>`instead of `>` to append to a file

Comment: Never mind got it working. it was because i was trying to run it inside the wmic shell